# Xcache - кеширование

Tags: php

Всем привет. Собрался вставить в сайт кеширование Xcache. (Выбрал его, так как только оно на хостинге присутствует).

В чем проблема. Не кеширует. Хотя ошибок не выдает.

Использую code-igniter. Добавлен класс в драйвера: CodeIgniter XCache Caching Class. Проверяю вот так вот:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
        $this->load->driver('cache');
}

public function test(){

    $go = "work";
    $this->cache->xcache->save('testing',$go,3600);
    if($this->cache->xcache->get('testing'))
    {
        return "It's Work";

    }else{
        return "Not work";
    }}
```

Возвращает "Not work".

Comment: @Nick, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: Хорошо, не знал.

Comment: Не знаком с CodeIgniter, но попробуй вместо фунции save() использовать set()

Comment: Суть в том, что save() обращается к библиотеке с классом функций, где у функции save() стоит xcache_set();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А не так ли пишется строка инициализации драйвера?

```
$this->load->driver('cache', array('adapter' => 'xcache'));
```

ну а потом использовать

```
$this->cache->save('mvar', array(0=>'dt',1=>'od'));
print_r($this->cache->get('mvar'));
```

зачем тебе

```
 $this->cache->xcache-> ***
```

Работай ты с этим.

```
$this->cache
```

Comment: Пробовал так и так, еще до того, как задал вопрос. В прочем, разницы нет.